# how do i get the member count using joins

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join

here is my database structure

```
              members table
                      member_Id


              membertomshiptable
                      membertomship_startdate
                      membertomship_enddate 
                      member_id
                      mshipstatustype_id

              membershipstatustypetable

                   membershipstatustype_id
                   membershipstatusname
```

I have membershipstatusname cloumn  has  value is completed . can i get how many members(count)  have membershipstatusname  is completed  starting  date from  membertomship_startdate.

and i have a doubt , I need to represent this on graph  i hav to take days on x-axis  and i hav to take members ids on y axis and i want to represent the how many members are having completed membershipstatus name with in one  month......

is it possible with query

can any one help on this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT membertomship_startdate,
           COUNT(member_id)
FROM       members  t1,

               membertomshiptable t2,
               membershipstatustypetable t3,
WHERE  t1.member_id=t2.member_id AND

            t2.mshipstatustype_id= t3.membershipstatustypetable  AND
            t2.membertomship_startdate> <specify the date here>  AND
            t3.membershipstatusname='completed' AND
GROUP BY   t2.membertomship_startdate
```

Answer (score 2):

Could this be what you're looking for?

```
SELECT     `membertomship_startdate`,
           `membershipstatusname`,
           COUNT(`member_id`)
FROM       `membertomshiptable`
LEFT JOIN  `membershipstatustypetable` ON
           `membershipstatustypetable`.`membershipstatustype_id` = `membertomshiptable`.`mshipstatustype_id`
GROUP BY   `membertomship_startdate`,
           `membershipstatusname`;
```

Or to search for "completed" membership where the "start date" is greater than certain date:

Could this be what you're looking for?

```
SELECT     `membertomship_startdate`
           COUNT(`member_id`)
FROM       `membertomshiptable`
INNER JOIN `membershipstatustypetable` ON
           `membershipstatustypetable`.`membershipstatustype_id` = `membertomshiptable`.`mshipstatustype_id` AND
           `membershipstatusname` = "completed"
WHERE      `membertomship_startdate` > "0000-00-00" AND
GROUP BY   `membertomship_startdate`;
```

Comment: not the membershipstatusname and i want only count and membertomship_startdate

Comment: @user682417 - The first query will show you a count of each status by date. I added a second query that will return the start date and the number of members for a specified status where the date is greater than one of your choice. You can always tweak the statements a little if you want.

Comment: dear francis there is a relation between members.member_id and membertomship.member_id. Is there any problem if we did not mention the above relation  ....

Comment: @user682417 - No. Since you're only interested in the number of memberships by date, there's no need to join that third table. The membership status table is associated to the membership status type table by status and you can differentiate each user by their member_id without having to join the members table. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I want number of members(count) having the  membershipstatusname is completed starting date from membertomship_startdate. not on number of memberships....

Comment: @user682417 - And how is a membership different than a member? Can a member have more than 1 membership? The second query I gave you will find count "memberships" where the "status" is "completed" and the "start date" greater than a date of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(member_id) JOIN membertomshiptable USING(member_id)
     JOIN membershipstatustypetable ON mshipstatustype_id=membershipstatustype_id
     WHERE membertomship_startdate <= 'XXXX-XX-XX' 
     AND membershipstatusname='complete'
```

If you know the status ID you want to check you could avoid the last JOIN. You might also need to specify an end date as well if you're looking for a specific month.